# Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException] error

Tags: php, symfony, twig, swiftmailer

Hi I stumble upon this error everytime I want to run my Symfony application from console. Therefore I am unable to use this symphony app at all. Please help me with your knowledge.

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]         
Unable to parse at line 9 (near "mailer_transport="gmail"") in
  /opt/lampp/htdocs/symblog.dev/app/config/parameters.yml (which is     
being imported from
  "/opt/lampp/htdocs/symblog.dev/app/config/config.yml").


[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]               
Unable to parse at line 9 (near "mailer_transport="gmail"").
```

Here is my /app/config/parameters.yml file (I have my true password in original file obviously)

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symblog_db
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport="gmail"
    mailer_encryption="ssl"
    mailer_auth_mode="login"
    mailer_host="smtp.gmail.com"
    mailer_user="mactestsymblog@gmail.com"
    mailer_password="xxxxxxxxx"

    secret: JaTylkoTrenuje
```

And my app/config/config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: @BloggerBlogBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: All your mailer_xxx param lines have = where there should be a :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873175/symfony-component-config-exception-fileloaderloadexception-error/30875208#comment49788366_30873175) by [redbirdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302002/redbirdo), you have `=` instead of `:` in your `parameters.yml`, which should be like this:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symblog_db
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: "gmail"
    mailer_encryption: "ssl"
    mailer_auth_mode: "login"
    mailer_host: "smtp.gmail.com"
    mailer_user: "mactestsymblog@gmail.com"
    mailer_password: "xxxxxxxxx"

    secret: JaTylkoTrenuje
```